# Serilog Owin Middleware

Tags: c#, logging, owin, serilog, owin-middleware

I'm trying to add a simple enrichment using `LogContext` in an Owin pipeline

My Logger configuration

```
// configure logger
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.WithProperty("B", 2)
            .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .CreateLogger();

app.Use(typeof(LoggerMiddleware));
```

My Owin middleware

```
public class LoggerMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public LoggerMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("A", 1))
        {
            await Next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
}
```

In the log I can see the property `B, 2` but not `A, 1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apperantly this has to do with [this issue](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/517). 
A workaround that worked for me is changing the order of the owin pipeline and placing the logging middleware after the authentication

```
AuthConfig.Configure(app);
LogConfig.Configure(app);
WebApiConfig.Configure(app);
```